# Add class and then fire an event JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add class and then fire an event, but unfortunately its not working and I think I am trying in wrong way, can somebody please suggest? Following are my codes

First I want to add class

```
$(".hospital_listing_front").addClass('flexslider-hospital');
```

Once the class is added then fire the following function (This is related to flexslider and will add flexslider functionality)

```
$(".flexslider-hospital").flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 48,
    pausePlay: false
    });
```

Add class is working but flexslider is not working

Please suggest how to handle this.

thanks in advance

Comment: Add class is working but flexslider is not working

Comment: There might be some another issue which you are not showing in code Post full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it may be have provide some time to add class. Like may be use setTimeout will solve your problem just try and let me know if you face again the same issue.

```
$(".hospital_listing_front").addClass('flexslider-hospital');

setTimeout(function() {
    $(".flexslider-hospital").flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 48,
    pausePlay: false
    });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Amazing, it worked when I added in setTimeout, thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Why not chain it?

```
$(".hospital_listing_front").addClass('flexslider-hospital').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 48,
    pausePlay: false
    });
```

or if you wish to step it:

```
 $hospital = $(".hospital_listing_front");
 $hospital.addClass('flexslider-hospital')
 $hospital.flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 48,
    pausePlay: false
    });
```

but if flex slider does't work, there might be an issue with your formatting of html.
without your html that's hard to say for sure..

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I also thought chaining would fix my problem but unfortunately not so I had to go with Settimeout option as suggested by @SudharsanS